# Download or working with such Large Dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, kaggle

The size of this [ML Competition dataset](https://www.hackerearth.com/challenges/competitive/SORDI-ai-hackathon-2022/machine-learning/object-detection-5-40d2cc61/) is very large.

Here are some issues I am facing:

- My PC is not that strong to process and work with this much large dataset.
- My internet connection is not that fast to download.
- My drive has only 10 GB left, so can't fetch this dataset with Colab either.
- Can't upload the dataset to Kaggle for the 404 issues.

So, basically, my question is how I should work for this kinda dataset and of course more efficiently.

I tried to create dataset with Kaggle giving the link of the URLs from the dataset link, but it was showing: *Unfortunately we could not create your dataset. Reason: An internal error occurred*.

Answer (score 1):

Use distributed system like Apache Spark framework. PySpark and Dask are very efficient to handle big data.

Comment: Actually, my question was, how can I save this data anywhere except drive, and within a very short time and cost?